# Aggregate table using SSIS from other fact table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, ssas

I have `fact_table`:

```
BTS | date-start | date-end | id_temp_start | id_temp-end | WeekNum | T | A | Pond
```

and I need to create another aggregate `fact_Table` by using this `fact_Table` because I need to measure `NumberOfBTS` by A and countries or `NumberOfBTS` by A and T

How can I do that?

Comment: Here -> "by" means "/" and "AND" means "*"   
NumberOfBTS by A 
i:e Count(BTS)/A  

NumberOfBTS by A and T
count(BTS)/A*T        is it so???

Comment: Because there is no relationShip between two fact Tables how can i do it wi Fact Table agregation